# What is the best way to versoining in install/ upgrade scripts?

Tags: magento-1.7, upgrade, install, versioning, script

Sometimes I use any of the following mentioned names to name the install/upgrade scripts in custom modules.

```
install-0.1.0.0.php
upgrade-0.1.0.0-0.1.1.0.php
upgrade-0.1.1.0-0.1.2.0.php

----------------------------

install-0.1.0.php
upgrade-0.1.0.0-0.1.1.php
upgrade-0.1.1-0.1.2.php
```

Is there a standard way to follow for this naming conventions for install/upgrade scripts?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware this is purely a matter of preference. I would assume the intended versioning should comply with `app/Mage.php`:

```
public static function getVersionInfo()
{
    return array(
        'major'     => '1',
        'minor'     => '4',
        'revision'  => '2',
        'patch'     => '0',
        'stability' => '',
        'number'    => '',
    );
}
```

So if you don't consider your releases as patches, I'd say you're fine with 3 parts.

Answer (score 1):

I would match the version numbers you are using in your config.xml file (which can be 3 or 4 numbers long).

Comment: They can be as along as they want. In `\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyUpdates` is a `compare_version` check, so you can do whatever this function gives you. But as Cags said, numbers and points are fine! :-)

Comment: His question mentioned 3 or 4 parts - but yes it can be anything that the compare_version can process.

Comment: Didn't read it that way, but as always, you are right :-)0